# What did the announcer say in this video?

Tags: listening-comprehension

What the announcer said when the ICE Train's door is closing in this video:

https://youtu.be/MrW3vRmQ5fs?t=185

I only heard the last bit "Eingeleitet" which may be something arround "Door closing initiated" for the whole phrase.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The voice is saying "Schließvorgang eingeleitet" (Closing procedure initiated).

Comment: Very German way to say it :)

Comment: @jpa: Written by an engineer, approved by a lawyer... :-)

Comment: @jpa The driver needs to distinguish between "procedure initiated", "procedure succeeded" and "procedure failed" (the latter is more common than you'd think with the automatic doors on certain models). The passengers (or rather, people on the platform) will only hear "Türen schließen." afaik.

Comment: It's intra-crew communication. You hear the same kind of verbiage in English on airplanes between cabin crew and cockpit.